# Pyaudio recognizer error cannot find path

Tags: python, path, system, pyinstaller, pyaudio

I have written a basic program that uses pyttsx, speechrecognition and tkinter libraries basically. I have a function like as follows.

```
def dunno():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print('1')
        textEntry = r.recognize(audio)
        print('2')
        print(textEntry)
        engine.say("You said: "+ textEntry)
        engine.runAndWait()
    except LookupError:
        engine.say("Sorry I couldn't understand what you said")
        engine.runAndWait()
```

Also I have defined my Recognizer and microphone as follows:

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
```

Then I have created an exe file using pyinstaller by using command prompt like as follows:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --onefile --name=somesing "C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\SomeFolder\mycodefile.py"
```

It is creating the .exe file without any problem. Also I have created another .exe file for another version that is without speech recognition but it and it is working well. This one gives an output with error like:

```
1
The system cannot find the path specified
1
The system cannot find the path specified
1
The system cannot find the path specified
```

Here I have called the function dunno() three times and have taken this error. The python script is working really nice butexe file is not working.

Edit: I have tried with a wav file too. I don't think problem is about Microphone. It should be about the recognizer inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that *speech_recognition*'s bundled FLAC conversion utility can't be located since *PyInstaller* doesn't know it's required.

Therefore, you need to explicitly ask *PyInstaller* to include it during the build process. Try creating a file called `hook-speech_recognition.py` with the following content:

```
from PyInstaller.hooks.hookutils import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('speech_recognition')
```

When building, supply the path to the directory in which you placed the file as a value to the `--additional-hooks-dir` argument, as follows:

```
--additional-hooks-dir=<path_to_directory_of_hook_file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoel is correct (but `speech_recognition` in the code should be in double quotes).

I have added detailed instructions for how to set up the library with PyInstaller in [this commit](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/commit/ac9bf913291813295f626292c86dac6522abf46a).

I have also submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/1296) to PyInstaller to include speech_recognition integration by default. Once merged, adding these hooks will no longer be necessary.

Comment: I believe this doesn't merit an answer of its own. Instead, I think you should just have posted this as a comment to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30805836/3903832). Doing so would have also notified me of my error, which I could have fixed immediately.

Comment: I agree, but I don't have enough reputation to comment on your post.